# Inlines referencing an owned foreign key

Tags: django, django-admin

I'm trying to write an inline editor for a specific type I'm writing. My types look like this:

```
class Person(models.Model):
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=30)

class Donor(models.Model):
    # a donor _is_ a person
    person = models.OneToOneField("Person")
```

The goal is to be able to edit the information stored in `Person` from a `Donor`, as `Person` is more of an abstract type (though not entirely). Here's my admin:

```
class PersonInline(admin.StackedInline):
    model = Person
    fields = ('first_name', 'last_name')

class DonorAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    inlines = (PersonInline,)

admin.site.register(Donor, DonorAdmin)
```

Unfortunately, when I go to create a new `Donor` in the admin site, I see the following error:

```
Exception at /core/donor/add/
<class 'core.models.Person'> has no ForeignKey to <class 'core.models.Donor'>
```

Odd. Why isn't it working with my very simple inline?

---

#### EDIT

I've found that it works if I change the location of the references to be on the `Person` class rather than on the `Donor`, but this really fouls up my design:

```
class Person(models.Model):
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    donor = models.OneToOneField("Donor", blank=True, null=True)
    recipient = models.OneToOneField("Recipient", blank=True, null=True)
    recipient_dependant = models.OneToOneField("RecipientDependant", blank=True, null=True)

class Donor(models.Model):
    pass

class Recipient(models.Model):
    pass

class RecipientDependant(models.Model):
    pass
```

This seems kind of backwards to me, because a `Donor` *is a/owns a* `Person` object, but a `Person` *is not/does not own* a `Donor`. Plus, this is a bit crazy. The `Person` class doesn't need to know necessarily what owns it at all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't have an inline for Person, but have the relationship owner (where the OneToOne field is) be the donor.

In your case, you would need a DonorInline and a PersonAdmin.

Comment: Unfortunately, `Person`'s really meant to be more of an abstract type. I have about 4 or 5 models that one-to-one to `Person`, it doesn't really make sense to put all of those references in `Person`, as they're kind of irrelevant to it. Is there another way of doing this?

Comment: This can't be done using the built-in Django Admin app, that I'm aware of. You may need to develop your own page to create/edit Person. Is there any reason why you can't declare Person abstract and have Donor, Recipient, etc inherit from Person?

Comment: If I can avoid it, I'd _like_ to, in favor of data normalization, but I guess it doesn't really matter at this point.